# Using Outbound Endpoints to Publish more Data in Mule

Tags: file, httprequest, mule, endpoint, outbound

i did a example from [Using Outbound Endpoints to Publish Data](http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Using+Outbound+Endpoints+to+Publish+Data)

i had not any problem but i want to save more information in  file outputted like ip or date

to wit When Http-request is sent and ip that sent http-request  save in to file  for the file that will be outputted.